# C# DataTable find rows not present in another DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have 2 DataTables. One representing Customers and the other representing CustomerContacts.

I need to find all the Customer rows which do not have any CustomerContact row.

Other than having 2 loops and using DataViews and FindRows to find which Customers do not have any contacts, is there a simpler way to code? I am not familiar with LINQ and do not wish to use it for my current project.

I am using .NET 4.5

I cant directly use SQL at database, as there is no "database". I am populating the DataTables by custom reading Excel files.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you really *should* begin to familiarize yourself with LINQ. It's become something of the standard for even the simplest of tasks and is something you're going to find in almost any code base. Even Microsoft pushes its use (one example being the TypeInfo class and filtering of its properties)

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code. It doesn't use any `LINQ`. Replace `customerID` with actual Id column of your tables.

```
DataTable Customers  = new DataTable();//fill this table from db
DataTable CustomersContacts = new DataTable();//fill this table from db
List<string> NoContactCus = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow Customer in Customers.Rows)
{
    DataRow[] contacts = CustomersContacts.Select(string.Format("customerID={0}", Customer["customerID"].ToString()));
    if (contacts.Count() == 0)
        NoContactCus.Add(Customer["customerID"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `LINQ` as below (a & b is two data table)

```
var query = (from x in a.AsEnumerable()
          join y in b.AsEnumerable() on x.Field<int>("col1") equals y.Field<int>("col1")
          select new { col1= y.Field<int>("col1"), col2=x.Field<int>("col2") }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is your friend.

```
var result = dtCustomers.AsEnumerable().Select(row => (int)row["id"])
    .Except(dtCustomerContacts.AsEnumerable().Select(row => (int)row["customerId"]));
```

Where
`dtCustomers` and `dtCustomerContacts` are data tables,
`"id"` and `"customerId"` are primary and foreign keys (assume that they are `int`),
`result` is list of customer Ids without any contacts.

Comment: Will the performance be better or worse compared to writing own 2 loops and using FindRows?